# How to link a check button(true/false) with a toggle list after that

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm having some trouble today. I need to put in a table from excel the name of 12 members of a project and their available days for work (name-availability), so I did a lot of check buttons for each person, as in the image :[table with members and their free days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65NJY.png)
But, after that, I need to create a toggle list with the days of week in a calendar and receive the name of the people based in their free days. Like:
Person1 can work mondays, wednesdays and saturdays. Person2 can work mondays, fridays and sundays. Person3 can work only at fridays.
And for that, have a list like this one:[The second table, with all the members, not with filtered members based in the days, "sexta-feira" is friday.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YN56C.png)
In this, I've tried to use the data validation table. But I want to create a list only with the name of the people that are available based in the table 1, not putting all the names of the members.
In this example, for the day 1st October, the list showing only Person2 and Person3 without Person1 because the P1 isn't available.
Somebody have a tip to me? Im really confused about how can I do that.
Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Creata a named range per each day of the week and refer to it via INDIRECT within the data validation table

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.